# WSO2 EI 6.1.1 post request body not send

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a problem with wso2 EI 6.1.1. I tried using call mediator to post data to an endpoint, where the data is created via class I've created.

The issue is that the body seems to be always empty. The resulted object from the class is not sent as the body.

```
<resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/itineraries">
        <inSequence>
            <property description="baseUrl" expression="get-property('boBaseUrl')" name="uri.var.boBaseUrl" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="InsiteoClientId" expression="get-property('InsiteoClientID')" name="clientID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="appVersion" expression="$trp:X-app-version" name="appVersion" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="buildingId" expression="$trp:X-current-building-id" name="uri.var.buildingId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="wayPoints" expression="json-eval($.)" name="wayPoints" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.boBaseUrl}/api/v1/buildings/{uri.var.buildingId}"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property description="floors" expression="json-eval($.floors)" name="floors" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="InsiteoSiteId" expression="json-eval($.information.insiteoIDSite)" name="uri.var.insiteoSiteId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <class description="ItineraryClass" name="com.capgemini.smartWorkPlace.Itinerary"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <header expression="get-property('InsiteoApiKey')" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="http://services.test.insiteo.com/APIV3/{uri.var.insiteoSiteId}/iti/process"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <log level="full"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

The request status code returns 500 as if no body was ever sent.

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

In your class mediator check if you're setting the created payload to the context body. If its json,

```
JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(axis2MessageContext, jsonPayload.toString(), true, true);
```

Comment: Hello, Yes I did that actually When I log the resulting payload of the class, I get a suitable json, I tried it with postman and it works. the issue is that this payload isn't transferred to the call

Comment: I Found that it's the first call that causes problem, it seems that ei doesn't modify the body